# Database with XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file with 5 million items. Each item has many data subcategories. I need to query this file to get data about an item with PHP.

I don't know where to start. Should I convert the XML file to a SQL database? Or are XML files a valid format for databases?

Comment: A good start would be to read up on what XML files, and MySQL databases are. This will then give you your answer. In short: Any data can be converted to fit in a MySQL database, but whether you should do that here depends on how you're going to use it. If you're only using it once, there's no point. If you need to query the data often, then sure, it makes sense.

Comment: everything depends on how often you need to do reads/writes/updates of the data (or, probably, it is an action for one time). 
I suspect that's something you need to access periodically and in this case, @KIKOSoftware made correct suggection. 
Mysql or other database engine (Who knows, maybe mayadb?) is definitely the next step.